# Handle anonymous class with Generics in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to write unit test using Powermockito for following method -

```
public String getGenerator(String json) throws IOException {
    String jwt = "";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // convert JSON string to Map
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    }); // Here passing TypeReference annonymously

    // Create a JWT
    JWTGenerator generator = new JWTGenerator();
    if (map != null && map.size() > 0) {
        jwt = generator.createJWT(map);
    }

    return jwt;
}
```

I have written test method as -

```
@Test
public void testGetJWTGenerator() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mockMapper = PowerMockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectMapper.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockMapper);

    JWTGenerator mockJWTDecoder = PowerMockito.mock(JWTGenerator.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(JWTGenerator.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockJWTDecoder);

    Map<String, Object> anyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    anyMap.put("testStr", new Object());

    TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> mockTypeReference = (TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>) PowerMockito.mock(TypeReference.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(TypeReference.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockTypeReference);

    PowerMockito.when(mockMapper.readValue(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(mockTypeReference))).thenReturn(anyMap);
    PowerMockito.when(mockJWTDecoder.createJWT(anyMap)).thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());
    utilityController = new UtilityController();
    utilityController.getJWTGenerator("{\"someStr\":\"someStr\"}");
    Mockito.verify(mockJWTDecoder, Mockito.times(1)).createJWT(anyMap);
}
```

When I run this test I always get it failed saying -

```
Wanted but not invoked:
jWTGenerator.createJWT(
    {testStr=java.lang.Object@24bdb479}
);
```

It looks like stub is not working as I always get "null" for this line -

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }); // Here passing TypeReference annonymously
```

Is it because anonymous instantiation of  TypeReference class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the anonymous inner class. Specifically, you tell PowerMockito to replace the call to `new TypeReference`:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(TypeReference.class).withNoArguments()
    .thenReturn(mockTypeReference);
```

But what you're actually creating is an anonymous class that extends TypeReference, not a TypeReference itself:

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(
    json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

This is going to be especially tricky for you. My normal advice here is "[don't mock data objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40596314/1426891)" like TypeReference, because it's a no-dependency token/value/data object that works heavily on reflection, but it also [doesn't support `equals`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/842e3416f8fecc2f317919ddfaf340df43bfeb6c/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java) the way its cousins in [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/8405f90aa92054802c73fa54c4fb2eede188e2bc/core/src/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.java) and [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/2a268346329c3ce17ad1269c5c0206ddd2747a17/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.java) do; unlike with Guice and Guava you couldn't just create your own real TypeReference in your test and match with Mockito's `eq`.

You still shouldn't mock TypeReference, but you'll also need to adjust how you assert against it:

- Extract the anonymous TypeReference subclass to a named equivalent, if Jackson lets you, and then use `isA` to check its type.
- Extract the TypeReference to a visible constant and check reference equality on it.
- Use a `Captor` and check the TypeReference's generic type using [`getType`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/842e3416f8fecc2f317919ddfaf340df43bfeb6c/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java).
- Create an [`ArgumentMatcher`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) implementation that uses `getType` and consume it with `argThat`.
- Switch to `ArgumentMatchers.any()` or `ArgumentMatchers.<TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>>any()`, which was previously on the `Matchers` and `Mockito` interfaces. The value is unlikely to change anyway, so pragmatically your system and test may be more readable and robust from disregarding the check than from convincing PowerMock otherwise.
- Ideally, use real dependencies wherever you can and just check that the function works, not that you're interacting with the right collaborators in the ways that your implementation happens to. A working function is what you're after anyway, right?

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I switched to Mockito.<TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>> any() and it works.

Comment: @Jeff bowman, I am also facing the same issue. Can you explain more or provide an example?

Comment: @Nimesh I can answer specific questions, but without knowing an area of focus or your constraints, I'm not sure what to write that I haven't already written. And as for examples, there are enough techniques I listed and enough ways this might be applicable that I'm not sure it makes sense to pre-emptively write a specific example for each.